# is there a way to use a class function inside the class with out $this ->

Tags: php, class

I was wondering, if there a way to use a class function inside another class function with out using `$this->`, for example:

```
class Example {
    public function sayhi() {
        echo "HI";
    }

    public function hi() {
        sayhi();
    }
}
```

Something like this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't. PHP knows functions and thus there would be no way to distinguish, wether `sayhi()` is a function, or a method.

Answer (score -1):

you could do it like this

```
<?php

class test {

  public function hi() {

    self::say();
  }

  private function say() {

    echo 'hi';
  }
}

$t = new test();
$t->hi();
?>
```

so yeah there IS a way to avoid $this but i dont recommend it.

Comment: A big downside to this is inside the `say()` function, its executing in the static context so you've completely lost the ability to use instance-specific methods or variables.

Comment: as i said i dont recommend it, yet its a way to come arround `$this` in the case of the askers example.

Comment: It's not just "not recommended", class- and object-context are two different things. You should increase your error-settings (on your development system). Anyway, only replacing `$this->` with `self::` has no benefit.